# How to batch rename files consecutively?

Tags: windows, batch-rename

I have a folder full of jpg images that have random names, and I need to rename them this way:

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
etc

I have 7 folders with these images, I would need to rename them considering the folders too, let me explain:

folder 1, 200 images, names:

1.jpg
2.jpg
...
200.jpg

folder 2, 150 images, names:

201.jpg
202.jpg
...
350.jpg

Basically the idea is that they are named differently from each other following the same autoincremental rule, even if they are in different folders.

What would be the best approach?.

Comment: I would do that in a simple small console application that I will write for this small task. Don't know any ready made tool for that task

Answer (score 0):

Advanced renamer will do this for you on a per folder basis.

http://www.advancedrenamer.com/